# Get key from json object, if the key is dynamically changing based on the GET request made

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<select id="crypto_list">
    <option value="BTC">BTC</option>
    <option value="ETH">ETH</option>
    <option value="LTC">LTC</option>
    <!-- If Other is chosen, then use text box to type in symbol  -->
    <option value="other_crypto" id="other_crypto">Other</option>
</select>
<!--  -->
<select id="currency_list">
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
    <option value="INR">INR</option>
    <!-- If Other is chosen, then use text box to type in symbol  -->
    <option value="other_currency" id="other_currency">Other</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript is:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url_final,
        data: "json",
        success: function(response){
            var price = response.USD;
            //
            if($("#crypto_list").val() == "other_crypto" && $("#currency_list").val() == "other_currency"){
                document.querySelector("#value_of_crypto_in_real_currency").innerHTML = "<h2>Price of " + typed_value_1 + " is " + price + " " + typed_value_2 +  "!</h2>";
            }
            else{
                document.querySelector("#value_of_crypto_in_real_currency").innerHTML = "<h2>Price of " + url_2 + " is " + price + " " + url_4 + "!</h2>";
            }
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert("There is an error");
        }
    });
});
```

Response is a JSON Object:

```
{"USD":8285.83}
```

If my Key (in this case it is USD) of my JSON object keeps changing, how would i get that value. For example, i could request the Response to be in EURO. But instead of changing my price variable manually to (response.EURO) i want to do that dynamically after the `onClick` of my dropdown. Any suggestions?

Comment: ```Object.keys(yourObj)``` will return an array of the keys for that object.  Does that help?

Comment: unfortunately not. but i think i found the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Object.keys` and then map the array to the values, like:

```
var price = Object.keys(response).map(key => response[key)[0];
```

*If I might suggest another change*

The following code:

```
if($("#crypto_list").val() == "other_crypto" && $("#currency_list").val() == "other_currency"){
    document.querySelector("#value_of_crypto_in_real_currency").innerHTML = "<h2>Price of " + typed_value_1 + " is " + price + " " + typed_value_2 +  "!</h2>";
}
else {
    document.querySelector("#value_of_crypto_in_real_currency").innerHTML = "<h2>Price of " + url_2 + " is " + price + " " + url_4 + "!</h2>";
 }
```

Could look better like this:

```
document.querySelector("#value_of_crypto_in_real_currency").innerHTML =
  $("#crypto_list").val() == "other_crypto" &&
  $("#currency_list").val() == "other_currency"
    ? "<h2>Price of " + typed_value_1 +" is " +price +" " +typed_value_2 +"!</h2>"
    : "<h2>Price of " + url_2 + " is " + price + " " + url_4 + "!</h2>";
```

Comment: for(x in response){
     price = response[x];
     //console.log(x);
    }

Comment: got the key and passed the key itself after doing a special for loop

Comment: and thank your for suggesting the change, much appreciated

Comment: yeah that also works, it is actually the same, I just prefer the function approach. (Probably using the `forIn` loop is better in terms of micro-performance)

Answer (score 0):

With `Object.keys` you can get all keys of an object, you can then take the first key, and use that to get your price.

```
var currency = Object.keys(response)[0];
var price = response[currency];
```